# Storage java jelastic

Tags: java, storage, jelastic

I have a java app in which I want to use Jelastic's storage container, since the application WAR is getting bigger than the maximum allowed by my provider.

Does any one have examples on how to upload files, and how to access those files in my Java app? I read some documentation on how to create the storage contained, but those weren't very useful.

Thanks
Dov

Answer (score 0):

Below you'll find some ways on how to upload big files:

- In the article [Upload and Deploy Your Java Application](https://docs.jelastic.com/upload-deploy-application) you can find the note with a description, concerning big files uploading to Deployment Manager:

> **Note** that the maximum available size of the uploaded local file is **150
>   MB.** If your application size exceeds this limit, please use the URL
>   for uploading.

Actually, size is depending on the chosen hosting provider.

So, you can upload your file to a suitable file- or FTP-storage first and then upload it to Jelastic Deployment Manager using the obtained link.

- A second way to upload a big WAR file is to connect Tomcat server via [FTP](https://docs.jelastic.com/ftp-ftps-support) and place the file in **webapps** folder.
- Another way, if you want to use [Storage](https://docs.jelastic.com/data-storage-container) container, is to mount storage to */opt/tomcat/webapps* and place your file in dedicated container, outside the main server. Also, you can [Mount External Server](https://docs.jelastic.com/mount-external-server) and put your file there (may affect the speed your application)

Comment: I think it my be an issue with my provider... I get an error message

Creation of mount point at /opt/tomcat/webapps has failed. Please check the appropriate server's availability, conformity of permissions and firewall settings.

Comment: Hello Dov, could you provide us with email you have registered at Jelastic platform? We can check. Also you can contact support service of your hosting provider.